# Scrape page with cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, web-scraping, cheerio

I am currently experimenting on a project where I need to push the content of my online shop wishlist to a database in order to display it in an anguar app.

The step I am currently struggeling with, consists in scraping the page the user is currently on (basically his wishlist) and exporting it as a json file (eventually directely push it in firebase real time database).

Basically I want to export following elements of the wishlist:
 - the products images urls
 - the products prices
 - the products titles
 - the products pages urls

When I run my code on some of these classes, I either get empty values or only one value back in my console.

Furthermore I havent figured out yet how to save the data logged in the console as a json file.

I took a random online shop to make some tests. 
Below is an example of what I have tried, here I try to extract the product names and print it into the console.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');


request('https://www.peek-cloppenburg.de/herren/', timeout = 1000, function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('p.productTile-brand.qa-product-tile-brand').each(function(i, element){
      var a = $(this).prev();
      console.log(a.text());
    });
  }
});
```

When I run it I get blank text in the console. I would like to print in the console the product names of the page and save them as a json file.

I would be grateful if you could help me figuring a solution to this problem out :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your concrete example the problem is, that the text of the selected element is empty. If you run your script in the browser and execute it, it will return `""` as well. After dropping the `prev()`-call, the names are listed in the browser, so should in your cheerio code as well.

```
console.log($(this).text());
```